# Clear elaboration validation function on "no" selection. Re-initiate function on "yes" selection

Tags: jquery, validation, unbind

I have a form that shows an elaboration question when the user clicks "yes", and hides it when the user clicks "no". I currently have it so if they click "yes", the elaboration question is required. My problem is that if they click "yes" and then click "no", the validation function will NOT clear no matter what I try. They have to click "yes" again and type something in the textarea in order for the form to actually submit. I have tried everything (jQuery unbind, clear, remove, and change) to no prevail. I want them to be able to click yes and no to their hearts content, and only require the additional textarea if their final selection is on "yes". So I need it to be able to clear the specific validation function under the `$('#1yes').click(function () {`, without clearing the `$('#affirmative1').show(1000);` when the `$('#1no').click(function () {` is activated. Thank you in advance,
Chase

Here is the jQuery:

```
          $('#1yes').click(function () {
              if ($('#1yes').is(':checked')) {
                  $('#affirmative1').show(1000);
                  $(function validation() {
                      $('#myform').ipValidate({

                          required: { //required is a class
                              rule: function () {
                                  return $(this).val() == '' ? false : true;
                              },
                              onError: function () {

                                  if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('element_container')) {
                                      $(this).wrap('<div class="element_container error_div"></div>').after('<span>' + $(this).attr('rel') + '</span>');
                                  } else if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('error_div')) {
                                      $(this).next().text($(this).attr('rel')).parent().addClass('error_div');
                                  }
                                  //alert('Form is ready for submit.');
                              },
                              onValid: function () {
                                  $(this).next().text('').parent().removeClass('error_div');
                                  $(this).focus();
                              }
                          },
                      });
                  });
              }
          });

          $('#1no').click(function () {
              if ($('#1no').is(':checked')) { $('#affirmative1').hide(1000); 
           //code to clear "validation" function
           }
          });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <div class="radio single_form_element">
        <div class="chk_div">
        <p>
          <label>1)  Do you have some involvement or financial interest that is, or could be perceived to be, in conflict with the proper discharge of your duties at the
    University?</label><br>
          <input type="radio" name="response1" value="yes" id="1yes" required>yes<br>
          <input type="radio" name="response1" value="no" id="1no" required>no
        </p>


        <div id="affirmative1" style="display:none; margin:0 4% 0 4%;">
        <fieldset>
        <p>
          <label>Describe the University-administered project and your involvement, also include information about federally-funded projects you are working on that could reasonably be affected by an outside financial interest:</label><br>
          <textarea name="comments1a" class="input_border input_width required" rel="Enter more info here!"></textarea>
        </p>
        </fieldset>

        </div>
        </div><!-- End CHK_DIV -->
    </div><!-- END SINGLE FORM ELEMENT(RADIO) -->
```

Comment: hard to help without knowing where the plugin `ipValidate` comes from. A demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem would be a big help

Comment: As you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/RrzN6/2/

Comment: Do you object to changing validation plugins? Much simpler using jQuery validate. Far less code to create. Is heavily used and well documented and supported

Comment: I appreciate your help. There has to be a way to clear a function on radio selection. I think I had something similar to jQuery validate before this one but it isn't as visually appealing in my opinion. Plus I had trouble with the absolute positioning of the validation text in my jQuery pager.

Comment: OK.. give me link to docs for this plugin, you aren't using it properly. validate plugin is extremely flexible, can make it do anything you want.

Comment: Here is the link to the js fiddle that is how it was supposed to be all along: http://jsfiddle.net/RrzN6/10/

Comment: that is the file, not the docs, already looked in file, no reference to docs or website

Comment: That is all the docs it uses for validation. The website has secure access through a university wide authentication system. Here is an old version of it seems you have put forth so much effort: http://academicanalytic.com/compliance/test3.html

Comment: found where it comes from since demo you provided is hotlinking code from this site  http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/03/22/highly-customizable-yet-simple-form-validation-jquery-plugin/ Most of the code you wrote is doing nothing. There is no `radio` class in your html, only validation on radios is from html5 `required` property which won't do anything in some older IE versions

Comment: That doesn't help me at all. The "required" property you are referring to was the driver for the previous validation I talked about earlier. I am no longer using that validation, but in that example both methods are present. All I want to know is how to clear/unbind the nested "validation" function on "1no" radiobutton click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a lot wrong in existing code. The only thing that was working at all was html5 `required` property on radios.

The context of `this` within all the handlers is wrong, the code is obviously copy/pasted from original site, but set up is different.

The `radio` class in plugin object doesn't exist, and plugin won't validate based on `type=radio`.

Also `$(document).ready(function{..` is same as `$(function(){..` and there is never any reason to nest one in the other. There is no reason to have more than one `document.ready` for this code at all.

Here is some working code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[name="response1"]').change(function () {
        var showDescription = $('#1yes').is(':checked');
        $('#affirmative1')[showDescription ? 'show':'hide'](1000);
        //$('.dependsRadio').prop('required', showDescription);
    });

    $('#myform').ipValidate({ 
        /* this class "dependsRadio" added to textarea html to make validation work*/       
        dependsRadio:{
             rule: function () {
                var yesChecked=$('#1yes').is(':checked');
                 return  yesChecked ? $(this).val() !='' :true;
            },
            onError: function () {
             alert('textarea not valid')
            },
            onValid: function () {

            }
        },
        /* class added to radio elements*/
        radioClass: { 
            rule: function () {
                return $('input[type=radio]:checked').length < 1 ? false : true;
            },
            onError: function () {
                 alert('radio not checked')
            },
            onValid: function () {

            }
        },

        submitHandler: function () {
               alert('form is valid');
            return false;/* debug mode*/
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VgG4M/1/

Strongly suggest in future using plugins with documentation which this one definitely has none

Comment: Thanks man it looks like it should work, I obviously need to study up on my jQuery some more. You are freaking awesome!!

Comment: don't copy paste code you can't follow...that was 90% of the problem. There are many well documented plugins for validation...using one with no docs and no API makes no sense

Comment: Please help me rank up charliefl for going out of his way to help everybody out.

Comment: +1 for the effort.  @ChaseGibbons, so why not vote him up and accept his answer?  And I agree with charlietfl... next project use the vastly popular and well supported jQuery Validate plugin.